# Using ST_Intersects inside of an ST_Within

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, st-intersects, trigger

I have a PostgreSQL trigger function getting executed by QGIS.  That is working fine.

I am trying to modify my function to count the number of points that fall within the intersection (clipped) geometry that is a 'subset' of the NEW geometry that was created by the user which executed the trigger.  Kind of like applying a cookie cutter to a new chunk of geometry that has not yet been committed to the database.

I am also not sure if I need to add anything to the function to discard the subset geometry after I calculate the number of points.

I know it's missing from the query below and that I need to use ST_Intersection to 'clip' the geometry.  I am getting syntax errors even with the ST_Intersects though in the pgAdmin query tool.  I suspect it's because I need a join or something.  What am I doing wrong? Or is there another way to do this?

t1 = layer containing points
t2 = large polygon layer that I want 'clip' in order to only get the intersection of it compared to NEW
NEW = new geometry feature that the user created in QGIS

```sql
NEW.col1 = (
    SELECT count(*) FROM t1
    JOIN t3 ON ST_Intersects(NEW.geom, t3.geom)     
    WHERE ST_Within(t1.geom, ST_Intersects(NEW.geom, t3.geom)));
```

Comment: Don't you mean `ST_Intersection` in the WHERE?  Of course, that may not work as intended if the result has edge overlap.

Comment: I do want the ST_Intersection but I also do not know how to write it to get what I want.

Comment: `ST_Intersects` has a *Boolean* return result. You **can't** use it there. Please [Edit] the Question to contain a graphic of what you want to accomplish, since words aren't working.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  I've answered the part about getting the count.  The rest of the question isn't clear to me.  Like, is the trigger supposed to discard the edits after it gets the count?  If so you just keep OLD.geom as the geom.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming from your code that you meant t3 is the large polygon, not t2.

Answer (score 0):

You're just doing 1 thing too many.  All you need is `st_intersects` with the new geom:

```
NEW.col1 = (
    SELECT count(*) FROM t1 
    JOIN NEW ON ST_Intersects(NEW.geom, t1.geom));
```

If I have misunderstood the question and you do, in fact, need the intersection, this is how you'd do it:

```
NEW.col1 = (
    select count(*) from t1 
    join
    (select st_intersection(geom,NEW.geom) geom from t3 where st_intersects(NEW.geom, t3.geom)) foo
    on st_within(t1.geom, foo.geom)
);
```

You might also want to include points that touch the boundary but aren't within it.  As suggested by dr_jts, you can use `st_coveredby` to get the points within and touching the polygon:

```
NEW.col1 = (
    select count(*) from t1 
    join
    (select st_intersection(geom,NEW.geom) geom from t3 where st_intersects(NEW.geom, t3.geom)) foo
    on st_coveredby(t1.geom, foo.geom)
);
```

Comment: Use `ST_CoveredBY` instead of `ST_Within or ST_Touches`.  Simpler and more performant.